# How to apply bounce animation to my text view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to apply bounce animation to my text. Is it possible to do that? If so, can you please tell me how? Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updated links [Thank you [kaay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034042/kaay) for indicating that all previous links are now 404]*

---

There is a [Bouncing Ball example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/BouncingBalls.html) in Android source, which can be your start point.

Another good resources are

- [Bouncing a ball on Android’s canvas](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/1733)
- [Android Animation Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html)